# Powered USB hub

Tags: raspberry-pi, 5v, diagram, usb-hub

I would like to know if the bellow montage is going to work. I will try to convert a cheap USB hub for a raspberry pi zero.

[image]

Comment: Basically yes, it will.

Comment: But based on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38576/can-the-pi-zero-act-as-an-usb-peripheral-device you shouldn't have to make a Frankenstein cable

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that will work. There is no functional difference between the "PWR" connector and your added "5V PSU" connector.

Comment: The PWR is the Pizero micro usb power in.